# Hroku issue on Deploying Node.js project - simple one

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have recently deployed simple node.js work which does web chatting, really simple piece of codes. But when I visited the URL deployed, it is said following:

> Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I have checked the log which is saying:

```
2016-10-18T05:25:28.021356+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
2016-10-18T05:25:28.021357+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app/web/index.js:3:17)
2016-10-18T05:25:28.021357+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
2016-10-18T05:25:28.021356+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
2016-10-18T05:25:28.021358+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
2016-10-18T05:25:28.021358+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
2016-10-18T05:25:28.021359+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
2016-10-18T05:25:28.021370+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
2016-10-18T05:25:28.152443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-18T05:25:28.982052+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=realtime-web-chat-simple.herokuapp.com request_id=93c0506d-02e9-4505-a357-9e8d6578d007 fwd="45.56.152.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-18T05:25:30.286843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=realtime-web-chat-simple.herokuapp.com request_id=2a3caade-896a-4ae2-8fd9-6e5ec66fed78 fwd="45.56.152.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My package.json is following:

```
{
    "name": "RealTimeWebChat",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "real time web chat using node.js power :D",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/CodeKnight986/webchat.git"
    },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "socket.io": "latest",
        "express-handlebars": "3.0.0",
        "express-session": "1.13.0",
        "passport": "0.3.2",
        "passport-local": "1.0.0",
        "html-entities": "1.2.0"
    },
    "author": "ray - codeknight"
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, okay forget it.
I have found that I did not add express module on my package.json file.
Adding it fixed the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If it works locally, perhaps it'd be good to [set Node and npm versions on package.json](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version), in order to use the same versions you use locally.

If it doesn't work, you could try adding a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile) too to specify the command to run

Comment: thank your for your answer, but it does not solve the issue. :-(